# Which theorem could be used?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I want to write the $p-$adic expansion of $6!$ in $\mathbb{Q}_3$.

I have to solve the congruence $x \equiv 6! \pmod {3^n}$, right?

I found the following:

$$x_0 \equiv 6! \pmod 3 \Rightarrow x_0 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

$$x_1 \equiv 6! \pmod {3^2} \Rightarrow x_1 \equiv 0 \pmod {3^2}$$

$$x_2 \equiv 6! \pmod {3^3} \Rightarrow x_2 \equiv 18 \pmod {3^3}$$

$$x_3 \equiv 6! \pmod {3^4} \Rightarrow x_3 \equiv 72 \pmod {3^4}$$

Using the formula $x_n=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i 3^i$, I found: $a_0=0,a_1=0,a_2=2,a_3=2$.

Is there a theorem I could use, in order to find the coefficients of the infinite series?

A theorem that states, for example, that the solutions we find are periodic?

Comment: For positive integers the base $3$ representation is equal to $3$-adic representation (but many authors reverse the order of terms). In particular, the representation is finite. Anyway, no theorems are needed for this.
$$6!=720=729-9=1000000_3-100_3=222200_3.$$

Comment: I haven't understood it :/ Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: Here in base three
$$720=222200_3=2\cdot3^5+2\cdot3^4+2\cdot3^3+2\cdot3^2+0\cdot3^1+0\cdot3^0,$$ which is exactly the same information we want a $3$-adic series to convey. Are you supposed to use Teichmüller representatives as digits instead of $0,1,2$? In this case the Teichmüller digits would be $0,1,-1$, so we would get away with $720=1\cdot3^6+(-1)\cdot3^2$.

Comment: Or $6!\equiv 720\pmod{3^6}$, $6!\equiv 720\pmod{3^7}$ and $6!\pmod 720\pmod{3^m}$ for all $m\ge6$. The rest of the digits are all zeros.

Comment: I haven't get taught  Teichmüller digits...
$$$$

How did you conclude that the rest of the digits are all zeros?

Comment: $x_n=720$ for all $n\ge5$, so $a_n=0$ for $n\ge6$. What's there to conclude?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So, you mean that it is like that?

$$$$

$$x_n=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i 3^i$$

$$x_0 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

$$x_1 \equiv 0 \pmod { 3^2 }$$

$$x_2 \equiv 18 \pmod { 3^3}$$

$$x_3 \equiv 72 \pmod { 3^4 }$$

$$x_4=6! \pmod {3^5} \Rightarrow x=6!+3^5=234 \pmod { 3^5 }$$

$$x_5=6! \pmod { 3^6 } \Rightarrow x \equiv 720 \pmod { 3^6 }$$

Since $6!=720, a_i=0 \forall i>5$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Or have I understood it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it seems you understand now that $720$, just like any other integer, has a finite $3$-adic representation, i.e. one of the form $$720=a_0 3^0+a_1 3^1+\cdots +a_n 3^n,$$ and you want to find the digits $a_0,\cdots, a_n$, where $0\leq a_i\leq 2$.

We will do it step by step.  How do we find $a_0$?  If we reduce the expression above modulo $3$, we get $720 \equiv a_0\pmod{3}$.  Do you understand this step?  All positive powers of $3$ go away because we took the remainder modulo $3$.

Now, $720 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ so $a_0\equiv 0\pmod{3}$.  But there is only one integer $a_0$ between $0$ and $2$ that is zero modulo $3$: the integer $a_0=0$.  Thus we found the zeroth digit!

On to the first digit.  We reduce the equation $720=a_0 3^0+a_1 3^1+\cdots +a_n 3^n$ modulo $3^2$.  What do we get?  All powers of $3$ above the first go away and we get $a_0+3a_1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3^2}$ (because $720$ is zero mod $9$).  Hmmm, we did not quite get $a_1$, but no worry.  We now know $a_0$ from the previous step, so how do we find $a_1$?

Since $a_0+3a_1$ is smaller than $9$ and zero mod nine, it has to equal zero in the integers.  This is a crucial property: if a quantity $q$ reduced modulo $M$ is equivalent to $a$ with $0\leq a < M$ and we know that $0 \leq q <M$, then actually $q=a$ as equality of integers. So in our case we get $a_0+3a_1=0$.

Now subtract $a_0$ (a digit we already know) from the equation $a_0+3a_1=0$ and divide by three to get $a_1$.  There, we found the first digit which (expectedly) equals zero.

On to the second digit: we reduce the equation $720=a_0 3^0+a_1 3^1+\cdots +a_n 3^n$ modulo $3^3$ to get $$a_0+3a_1 + 9a_2 \equiv 18 \pmod{3^3}.$$  Again, since $a_0+3a_1+9a_2< 27$ we conclude that $$a_0+3a_1 + 9a_2 = 18. $$ But from our previous divsion we had obtained $$a_0+3a_1=0.$$  Subtracting the equations and dividing by $9$, we find $a_2 = 2$.  This gives us the second digit.

In general, this is the procedure: reduce your number modulo powers of $3$ consecutively.  The first power will immediately give you the zeroth digit.  To get the $k$-th digit, reduce $720$ modulo $3^{k+1}$ and modulo $3^k$; consider these remainders as integers, subtract them and divide by $3^k$.  The integer you will get is your $k$-th digit.

So for instance you already computed $720 \equiv 234 \pmod{3^5}$ and $720 \equiv 72 \pmod{3^5}$.  Subtract $234-72 = 162$ and divide that by $3^4$ to get $a_4=2$.

When do we stop?  Your partial expressions $a_0+\cdots +a_k 3^k$ will be smaller than 720 but steadily increasing as you add more and more digits $a_k$, and eventually will become equal to 720.  This is where you will stop. (If you continue, the previous process will keep giving you zero digits forever).

I hope this helped, but if you still have unclear points I think you should make a serious review of congruences and their laws before tackling $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: Could you explain me how we conclude that $a_0+3a_1+9a_2<27$ ?

Comment: All the digits $a_i$ are smaller than or equal to $2$, by definition of what a $3$-adic digit is.  So $$a_0+3a_1+9a_2\leq 2+3\cdot 2 + 9\cdot 2 = 26<27.$$

Comment: So, when we solve the conruence $\pmod{3^k}$, is it $a_i \in \{0,1,2 \}$ and not $a_i \in \{0,1,2, \dots, 3^k-1 \}$ ?

Comment: The indivdiual digits are from zero to two; it is the partial sums $a_0+\cdots+a_{k-1}3^{k-1}$ that are between zero and $3^k-1$.  You need to understand the distinction.  The digits are not themselves the remainder of division by $3^k$.  That is the partial sum.  The digits are formed by subtracting two consecutive remainders and dividing by the larges power of three that divides the difference.  Just look at base 10, it is the same procedure.  The digits of 430942 are all between zero and nine; the remainded with division by 1000 is the partial sum of the first three digits.

Answer (score 0):

Every $p$-adic number has a well-defined $p$-adic expansion. When we take an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ and represent it in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, we have very little to do.

You are asking about $6! = 720$ in $\mathbb{Q}_3$. The coefficient of $3^n$ will be $720 \pmod {3^n}$. For $n \geq 6$, we see that $3^n > 720$. So the coefficients for all $3^n$ with $n \geq 6$ will be $720$. It is characteristic of the (normal) integers that they have finite (in this sense) expansions.

You are just left with finding the coefficients for the other $n \leq 5$. Quickly, we see that 
$$\begin{align}
720 &\equiv 0 &\pmod 3\\
 &\equiv 0 &\pmod {3^2}\\ 
&\equiv 18 &\pmod {3^3}\\
&\equiv 72 &\pmod {3^4}\\
& \equiv 234 &\pmod{3^5}\end{align}$$

and this gives us the entire expansion.

Comment: mixedmath Is there a formula you used, in order to calculate, for example, $720 \pmod{ 3^5}$?

Comment: I don't understand this. It looks like what you get when you view $\mathbb{Z}_3$ as the projective limit of $\mathbb{Z}/(3^k)$, but I don't see how that works for $\mathbb{Q}_3$. How would you represent e.g. $\frac{1}{3}$ in that form?

Comment: @DanielFischer How else could we do it? :/

Comment: @Daniel ah, I'd actually meant that it's easy to represent integers. Sorry about that.

Comment: @evinda As Jyrki Lahtonen did in the comments to the question, it's an integer, so it has a base-$3$ expansion, and we can write $6! = 720 = 2\cdot 3^2 + 2\cdot 3^3 + 2\cdot 3^4 + 2\cdot 3^5 = \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k 3^k$ with $a_k = 2$ for $2\leqslant k \leqslant 5$, and $a_k = 0$ for $k > 5$. That's what I know as a $3$-adic expansion. It seems that you need to include what kind of $p$-adic expansion you are looking for in your question, something of the form $\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k p^k$, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a p-adic expansion of the form $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} a_k p^k$. How do we find that $720=2 \cdot 3^2+2 \cdot 3^3+ 2 \cdot 3^4+2 \cdot 3^5$ ?